# Composite table storage query

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

the following function should return the list of items with a specific PartitionKey and TimeStamp included between two dates

```
    public async Task<List<T>> RetrieveEntityDataAsync<T>(string deviceId = null) where T : TableEntity, new()
    {
        try
        {
            TableQuery<T> DataTableQuery = new TableQuery<T>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceId))
            {
                var filter =  TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, deviceId);
                var filter1 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToUniversalTime().ToString());
                var filter2 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString());
                var combined = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter, TableOperators.And,filter1);
                var total = TableQuery.CombineFilters(combined, TableOperators.And, filter2);
                DataTableQuery = new TableQuery<T>().Where(total);
            }

            var l = new List<T>();
            TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
            do
            {
                var queryResponse = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(DataTableQuery, continuationToken);
                continuationToken = queryResponse.ContinuationToken;
                l.AddRange(queryResponse.Results);
            }
            while (continuationToken != null);
            return l;
        }
        catch (Exception ExceptionObj)
        {
            throw ExceptionObj;
        }
    }
```

Sending it does not work and goes to exception by returning "StorageException: Bad Request". What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you provide, you want to filter your Azure Table entities by date-time. I suggest you use `TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate` to create the condition.
For example

```
 CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionStr);
            var client =account.CreateCloudTableClient(new TableClientConfiguration());
            var table =client.GetTableReference("people");
            string date1 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate(
                   "Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual,
                   DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToUniversalTime());

            string date2 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate(
                               "Timestamp", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual,
                               DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());
            var key = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Jack");
            string filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(date1, TableOperators.And, date2);
            filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter, TableOperators.And, key);
            var query = new TableQuery<Person>().Where(filter);
            var l = new List<Person>();
            TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
            do
            {
                var queryResponse = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken);
                continuationToken = queryResponse.ContinuationToken;
                l.AddRange(queryResponse.Results);
            }
            while (continuationToken != null);

            foreach (var s in l) {

                Console.WriteLine(s.PartitionKey + "" + s.);
            }
```

[image]